# What's the offical name of using function call operator as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use type trait with functor, below is the code:

```cpp
struct fun {
  template <class T>
  constexpr auto operator()(T a) const  {
    return 0;
  }
};

template<class T> 
struct types{};
```

I'm curious about what's the official name of the usage `types<fun(int)>`, probably getting the type of the function call operator?

Answer (score 1):

`fun(int)` is the type of a function that takes an `int` and returns a `fun`.

It is unrelated to `fun::operator()`.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the answer, I mistakenly thought it was related to some advanced template usage : )

Answer (score 1):

> what's the official name of the usage `types<fun(int)>`

It (`types<fun(int)>`) is called a [template-id](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates):

> ##### template-id
>
> ```
> template-name <parameter-list >
> ```

---

As you can see the *template-id* consists of 2 parts:

1. *template-name*: which is `types` in your example.
2. *parameter-list*: which is `fun(int)` which itself is a **function type** in your example.